# hibernate Spatial with oracle not work correct?

Tags: hibernate, maven, oracle-spatial, hibernate-spatial

I'm working on GIS project.

In that I want produce a web GIS by JSF + Hibernate.

My Spatial data is in Oracle-Spatial 12c, for some Spatial Analysis I must be connect to Oracle DB and insert update a spatial Table.

I see this link Hibernate-Spatial

I first try to do this with Maven project in Net Beans 8.02 but not that work correct!!

And finally I have done these Step:

1. creates a web Application with net Beans 8.02 with hibernate 4.3 and JSF
2. Do the Step of this for the Hibernate

   https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html
3. Download jar files of Geo-tools from this link and add to my Project

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/geotools/files/
4. Download the Jar file of the hibernate-spatial 4.3 from this link and ojdbc7

   http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/01-download/01-releases/
5. Add two Spatial Table to My project(LINE  POINT)
6. a setting up this Steps in my project and my Line and point Class and .hbm.xml

   http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/05-oracle/

   http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/documentation/
7. When I Build my project in net Beans and try get a Query this From Line this Error show

   > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
   >   at org.hibernate.spatial.GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.getExtractor(GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.java:57)
   >   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
   >   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:259)
   >   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
   >   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:334)
   >   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
   >   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
   >   at      org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:939)
   >   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
   >   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
   >   at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)

Please help me how solve the problem Or
is a best Solution than hibernate-spatial?

Comment: Can you share details related to configuration like setting dialect

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is using a wrong dialect. The `OracleSpatial10gDialect` of Hibernate Spatial (HS) 4.3 will take care of those GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor re-mapping to a SDOGeometryTypeDescriptor which implements the [SqlTypeDescriptor.getExtractor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/SqlTypeDescriptor.html#getExtractor(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptor)) (see the [remapSqlTypeDescriptor](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/javadoc/4.0/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/oracle/OracleSpatial10gDialect.html#remapSqlTypeDescriptor(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.SqlTypeDescriptor)) function in HS 4.3).
So check your hibernate/persistence.xml configuration for the next properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.spatial.connection_finder">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.DefaultConnectionFinder</property>
```

See this link for an [explanation of connection_finder](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/05-oracle/).

Be aware that you must use HS 4.3 because you are using Hibernate version 4.3. For father problems keep in mind this version of HS was tested on Oracle 10g and 11g but it says nothing about Oracle 12c.